# How to pass data with next router without showing it in the URL?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am using next router and I want to pass data to another page but I don't want the data to be shown in the URL

I have a button once clicked it redirects to another page and pass an object `myObject` to it.

```js
const router = useRouter();
const myObject = {
  proprety1: "example1",
  proprety2: "example2",
  proprety3: "example3",
}
//...
<button
   onClick={() => {
     router.push({
       pathname: "/next-page",
       query: { data: JSON.stringify(myObject) },
     });
   }}
 >
   Navigate
</button>
```

Then in `next-page` I get this as URL :

`http://localhost:3000/next-page?data=%7B"proprety1"%3A"example1"%2C"proprety2"%3A"example2"%2C"proprety3"%3A"example3"%7D`

This works fine to be clear, but it is really ugly, not just that, I don't want data to be shown to users in the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use the second parameter `as` in the `router.push` function in order to accomplish what you want.

`router.push(url, as, options)`

See [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush).

Comment: can you provide a full example ?

Comment: A full example would be helpful.

Comment: Wrong answer, this just not work

Answer (score 4):

`as` props works fine with `next/link` and you can hide query parameters with `next/link` as well:

```js
<Link
  href={`/blogs/${item.slug}?id=${item.id}`}
  as={`/blogs/${item.slug}`}
  passHref
>
  <a href="" className="hover:text-cyanBlue">
    Read More
  </a>
</Link>
```

But keep in mind, this won't work if you set `target="_blank"` to anchor tag, or open link to the next tab of browser.

Comment: with next router not with next link

Comment: You can not get the data then in next page if using as, please address this